# Java - Google GSON syntax error

Tags: java, json, gson, syntax-error

So I'm trying to parse a request that comes in JSON format, but the Google GSON library throws a syntax error.

The request looks like this: `{"action":"ProjectCreation", data:{"projectName": "test project"}}`.

Which doesn't look like it has a syntax error to me...

Here is the error that GSON gives me:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 20 path $.

**EDIT:**

I fixed the syntax error in the JSON request, it now looks like this `{"action":"ProjectCreation", "data":{"projectName": "test project"}}`.

GSON is still throwing the same error....

**EDIT:**

The code responsible for parsing the request looks like this:

```
private Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
private String action;
private String responseAction;
private Map<String, String> data;
private Type dataType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
private Gson gson = new Gson();
private String requestId;
private Client client = new Client("127.0.0.1", 5699);

/**
 * Constructor for this class, sets initial parameters
 * @param request
 * @param _requestId 
 */
public ActionThread(String request, String _requestId) {
    System.out.println(request);
    //Parse the request into a map
    Map<String, Object> _request = gson.fromJson(request, type);
    //Give action the correct naming convention
action = _request.get("action") + "Request";
    responseAction = _request.get("action") + "Response";
    //Parse the data into a map
    String _data = _request.get("data").toString();
    data = gson.fromJson(_data, dataType);
    //Set the request id
    requestId = _requestId;
}
```

Comment: The key data should be quoted.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice that...

Comment: I'll change it and see if it fixes this.

Comment: as @AlexisC. commented your json should look like this:

{
 "action": "ProjectCreation",
 "data": {
  "projectName": "test project"
 }
}

but to be able to help you more, please add s code snippet, it will help more

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Show us a small, self-contained Java program that throws the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_request.get("data").toString()` is not the JSON representation of your data object. It's the string representation of the inner map you just parsed that is equal to `{projectName=test project}`.

One easy and quick way to solve this would be to convert your data object into its JSON representation and then parse it again:

```
Map<String, String> data = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(_request.get("data")), dataType);
```

It might be worth to consider having dedicated classes as well, for instance:

```
class Action {
    @SerializedName("action")
    String name;
    Data data;
}
class Data {
    String projectName;
}
```

and then

```
Action action = gson.fromJson(request, Action.class);
```

If you want to have the nested data object as a field directly in the Action class you could also write a custom deserializer.